# Can I put a relativistic energy of an electron using $\frac{p'^2}{2m}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, momentum, energy-conservation

I'm trying to derive Compton's scattering and I was a little skeptical of using $E=\frac{p'^2}{2m}$, where $p'$ is relativistic momentum to describe the relativistic energy of an electron. My second question is, if I have a relativistic momentum and nonrelativistic momentum $p'$ and $p$ then is $(p'-p)$ relativistic too? I would assume it is because the final value is still dependent on the Lorentz factor even if it's a little different.

Comment: For Compton scattering, do not treat the electron non-relativistically; use $E^2=m^2c^2+p^2c^2$.

Comment: Okay. can We just make mass and momentum relativistic and just have $E=p^'2/2m'$?

Comment: No, that doesn’t work.